# How to convert Date field into timestamp in logstash config file?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I wrote Logstash configuration file which reads one csv file and indexes it in elasticsearch. But i am facing some problems in doing so.

1) In my input file I am unable to convert date column into timestamp. The value of date column in csv file is:

- 1/22/2016 20:38  [m/d/yyyy H:mm]

So anyone can please tell me how to convert date column into timestamp in kibana ?

2)Moreover, can anyone also tell me how to convert latitude and longitude columns into geoip. the problem is that i only have latitudes and longitudes , i don't have source which is mandatory field in geoip filter.

eg: complaint_latitude: 12.91518877
    complaint_longitude: 77.48066853

so i am not sure what to put in source field

```
geoip {
    source => "??"
    }
```

3) While processing some lines in my file, logstash gives me following error:
Error parsing csv file. Not all lines shows me this error but very line does so i am losing lot of data as i am unable to index it.

**Here is my logstash config file:**

```
input{

    file{
         path =>["D:\Project\Logstash Config\Icmc\complaints.csv"]
         start_position => "beginning"
         #sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
         sincedb_path => "/tmp/since.db"
        }

   }

  filter{

      csv{
            separator => ","
            columns =>["category_name", "complaint_sub_category_iid", 
                       "parent_cat_name", "category_parent_iid", 
                       "civic_agency_name", "complaint_title", 
                       "complaint_user_iid", "user_iid", "user_full_name", 
                       "complaint_mobile_number", "complaint_ward_iid", 
                       "ward_name", "complaint_location",  
                       "complaint_address_1", "complaint_latitude", 
                       "complaint_longitude", 
                       "complaint_created","latest_comp_satus_id", 
                       "latest_comp_status_name", "complaint_description"]

            remove_field => ["message"]
        }

     mutate{
         convert => { "complaint_latitude" => "float"}
         }
    mutate{
         convert => { "complaint_longitude" => "float"}
          }
     }

filter{
     geoip {
         source => "clientip"
          }
     }

filter{

        date{
            match => ["complaint_created", "M/d/yyyy H:mm"]
            target => "@timestamp"
           }

        mutate{
            add_field => ["[geoip][lnglat]" , "%{[complaint_longitude]}", 
                     "tmplat", "%{[complaint_latitude]}"]
             }

        mutate{
            merge => ["[geoip][lnglat]", "tmplat"]
             }

        mutate{
            convert => ["[geoip][lnglat]", "float"]
            remove_field => ["tmplat"]
            remove_field => ["complaint_created"]
             }
   }


  output{
        elasticsearch{
        hosts =>["localhost:9200"]
        index => "icmc"
        #document_type => "complaints_filed"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "elastic"
        }

        stdout {  }
      }
```

Comment: Suggest splitting your question up into three.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, Since Kibana uses `@timestamp` field, you can possibly use `@timestamp` in your csv filter in place of the date column (`complaint_created`?) or use a `date` filter to target @timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion sammy, but i solved that. In kibana after selecting index pattern (step 1). in step 2, I selected "i don't want to use the time filter" which worked perfectly fine. Now i am looking for answer for question number 2